# ORA-00926 Missing Values Keyword

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

Beginner in SQL i'm currently unable to run this insert basic command.

```
insert into Project(ProjId,MedicName,Purpose,Start_date,End_date,PI_Id)
insert into Project values('PR003','Medic3','lung','01-Nov-14','31-DEC-20','10101');
```

> ERROR at line 2:
>   ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

Comment: Check your syntax. `INSERT INTO` syntax is `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong.  You need to write one statement:

```
insert into Project(ProjId,MedicName,Purpose,Start_date,End_date,PI_Id)
values('PR003','Medic3','lung','01-Nov-14','31-DEC-20','10101');
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the wrong syntax (you've already been told that), as it appears that certain columns in that table are `DATE` datatype, I'd suggest you not to enter strings into it, but dates. Becuase, both `'01-Nov-14'` and `'31-DEC-20'` *are* strings.

Don't rely on Oracle's implicit conversion. As long as it might work *now*, it'll fail sooner or later (when NLS settings change) not necessarily on this database, but on some other. For example, your values wouldn't fit into my database because my format is different, as well as language (we don't use English names). Take control over it.

You could

- use date literal (which I used for `start_date`)
- use `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask (`end_date` below)

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO project (projid,
                     medicname,
                     purpose,
                     start_date,
                     end_date,
                     pi_id)
     VALUES ('PR003',
             'Medic3',
             'lung',
             DATE '2014-11-01',                      --> this
             TO_DATE('31.12.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    --> this
             '10101');
```